# possible to search two form of hex string in one time?

Tags: neovim, search

Some text file contains lots of hex strings, a same string presents multiple times in two formats like:

```
00000000 aa bb cc 25 41 f3 d9 ed 58 5c ed a0 3c 61 60 ce ...%A...X..<a`.
```

and

```
aabbcc2541f3d9ed585ceda03c6160ce
```

When I search the string, I have to search twice, first for `aa bb cc`, and then search for `aabbcc`. Is it possible to search once, that would highlight both with-space and none-space strings? And press `N` to jump through these results just like normal search?

Comment: Have you ever heard of regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help /` should get you to `:help pattern`, from which you can learn all about vim’s syntax for patterns. Since they can used in more places than just `/`, it’s worth an initial read.

In your case, one option is `/\vaa ?bb ?cc`